# Displaying data for radio button in epicor ERP10

Tags: epicorerp, epicor, epicor10

I want to display data. I used AfterFieldChange method to display the data but it turns out the radio button doesn't change. I already insert the data customer table, the BAQ (Business Activity Query) also work just that the screen form doesn't work.

```
    private void UD24_AfterFieldChange(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs args)
{
    // ** Argument Properties and Uses **
    // args.Row["FieldName"]
    // args.Column, args.ProposedValue, args.Row
    // Add Event Handler Code
    //EpiDataView edvUD24 = ((EpiDataView)(this.oTrans.EpiDataViews["UD24"]));
    //System.Data.DataRow edvUD24Row = edvUD24.CurrentDataRow;

    EpiDataView view = oTrans.EpiDataViews["UD24"] as EpiDataView;
    switch (args.Column.ColumnName)
    {
        case "Character03":
            DataTable tblcust=customer(args.Row["Character03"].ToString());
            if(tblcust!=null && tblcust.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                string client = tblcust.Rows[0]["Customer_client1_c"].ToString();
                view.dataView[view.Row]["ShortChar04"] = client;
                //MessageBox.Show(Client);
            }
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It might help if you edit your question and post some code. For example the AfterFieldChange? method. Also, what are you trying to do? (Search for x-y problem)

Comment: I already edited it. this code supposedly display data. but in my case this code does not function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the data in the EpiDataView you need to call Notify to make it call the UI elements that need to be updated:

```
view.dataView[view.Row]["ShortChar04"] = client;
view.Notify(new Ice.Lib.Framework.EpiNotifyArgs(this, view.Row, NotifyType.Initialize));
```

Comment: how do I declare Notify? because I tried put it in it says notify doesn't exist. for data view this is the code right `EpiDataView view = oTrans.EpiDataViews["UD24"] as EpiDataView;` how to do for notify? emm

Answer (score 0):

Kieym, perhaps try adding EpiNotifyArgs into your declaration, like so:

```
private void UD24_AfterFieldChange(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs args, EpiNotifyArgs args)
```